# Numpy/pandas___How to undo an array?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, list-comprehension

I am doing an exercise a nd this is required:
Use a list comprehensions to create a list that contains all the elements of the 5 x 2 x 3 Numpy matrix below.

```
zeta = np.array([[[0.55867166, 0.06210792, 0.08147297],
    [0.82579068, 0.91512478, 0.06833034]],

   [[0.05440634, 0.65857693, 0.30296619],
    [0.06769833, 0.96031863, 0.51293743]],

   [[0.09143215, 0.71893382, 0.45850679],
    [0.58256464, 0.59005654, 0.56266457]],

   [[0.71600294, 0.87392666, 0.11434044],
    [0.8694668 , 0.65669313, 0.10708681]],

   [[0.07529684, 0.46470767, 0.47984544],
    [0.65368638, 0.14901286, 0.23760688]]])
```

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: How are those numbers generated?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what order you want them in, but this comprehension flattens it:

```
[z for x in zeta for y in x for z in y]
```

which you can check with

```
all([z for x in zeta for y in x for z in y] == zeta.flatten())
```

Try and understand what this answer does, before you move on to the next exercises. And maybe look into `help(zeta.flatten)`